# Does Speaker Size Matter?

Tags: speakers, monitors, loudspeakers

I own some decent bookshelf speakers that have good sound quality. I position them well within my room, symmetrically a few meters in front of my desk.

I have recently been to other places that have *large* speakers, probably 10x or 20x as large as mine in area. And even on a low volume -- comparable to normal listening from my bookshelf speakers -- the experience feels physically different, like being bathed in diffuse sound as opposed to the audio coming from two centers.

Maybe it's the acoustics of the space or whatever else, but I want to ask: *beyond loudness, does speaker size matter?* Do larger speakers achieve finer sound or better spread sound waves in a room? In other words, between small and large speakers of comparable quality and price, should you elect for the large ones?

Comment: There's so much more to speaker construction than just size. You simply cannot choose based on this one criterion.

Comment: @Tetsujin I understand that. My question is: all other factors being equal, does size make a difference?

Comment: Other factors are not equal. I have a sub attached to my living room 5.1, cost maybe 300, bends the walls. Two front L/R, about the same size, cost maybe 800, can't compete at the bottom end, but beat the cr*p out of the sub at the top. I have a stereo pair in my studio, cost twice as much as all those, beats the whole lot, top to bottom. If you take it to extremes, big speakers can have an extended low-end, but that really is not the defining factor. You cannot walk into a shop thinking the bigger ones are better because of their size. It just doesn't work like that.

Comment: Yes, it matters. But it’s not the only thing that matters

Comment: The way your question is worded makes it entirely opinion-based. You may be able to salvage a useful question here, but Tetsujin and Todd have given you the real answer